Equivariant Künneth formula for partial flag variety
Let $G$ be a simply connected simple algebraic group over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $P$ be a parabolic subgroup of $G$, $\mathscr{F}:=G/P$ the partial flag variety associated to $P$. For a $G$-variety $X$, let $K_0^G(X)$ be the Grothendieck group of $G$-equivariant coherent sheaves on $X$.
Can we have an isomorphism $$K^G_0(\mathscr{F})\otimes_{R(G)}K^G_0(\mathscr{F})\simeq K_0^G(\mathscr{F}\times\mathscr{F})$$ via the canonical map $(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G})\mapsto\mathcal{F}\boxtimes\mathcal{G}$?
Here $R(G)$ is the representation ring of $G$, which we identify with $K^G_0(pt)$ canonically.
Remark: The above is true for the flag variety case, which was first proved by Kazhdan and Lusztig in their paper "Proof of the Deligne–Langlands conjecture for Hecke algebras. Invent. math （87）153–215 (1987)".

That is certainly true after tensoring over $R(G)$ with its fraction field (by the Atiyah—Bott Localization Theorem).

@Jason Starr Yes, $K^G(\mathscr{F})\otimes_{R{G}}K^G(\mathscr{F})$ and $K^G(\mathscr{F}\times\mathscr{F})$ are both free as $R(G)$-modules with same rank. But take localization may lose many information, that is not I want.

There is the method of Goresky-Kottwitz-MacPherson (which, unlike Atiyah-Bott Localization, does preserve torsion).  This is usually formulated as a theorem on equivariant cohomology.  However, it might also apply to equivariant K-theory (up to passing to $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces, it should, since the Chern character gives an isomorphism between K-theory and Chow theory).

@Jason Starr Could you show me a reference please? Thanks a lot! :)

Theorem 1.2.2 of the following article of Goresky, Kottwitz and MacPherson: https://www.math.ias.edu/~goresky/knew2.pdf

@JasonStarr, thanks!:)
